# Proof for a combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, pigeonhole-principle

i have the following problem. 
There are 7 different kind of balls and 10 boxes. The balls are distributed into the boxes so that each box must contain 5 different balls. 
Prove that at least one type of ball appears in at least 8 boxes. 
 
I have a proof to this but i dont understand it. 
 
 
proof with contradiction: 
Distribute 10*5 = 50 balls 
Assumption: There is no kind of ball in more than 7 boxes. 
How many balls can you at the most distribute, under the assumption? -> 7*7 = 49, 
there are not enough balls (this is the contradiction).

I dont understand how this makes sense. Why is this the contradiction?

Comment: Let $n_i$ be the number of boxes containing ball $i$.  Then the total number of balls in all the boxes is $\sum_{i=1}^7n_i$.  If each $n_i≤7$ then that total is $≤7\times 7=49$.  But there are $50$ balls in all the boxes.

Comment: If each box must contain 5 different balls, then of course each box contains at least one ball. I do not understand the question.

Comment: @wimi the question is very poorly phrased, but I understand it to mean "prove that at least one type of ball appears in at least $8$ boxes.".  At least, that's what the sketched argument purports to address.

Comment: @lulu yes thats how the question meant to be. Sorry i had to translate it from german.

Comment: And does my first comment clarify things for you?

Comment: @lulu Yes thank you!